# Java - Referencing to an Array

Tags: java, arrays

The following is the code snippet:

```
int[] cdb1 = {2,1,1,5,5};
int[] cbd2 = {3,1,1,2,2,6,6};
int[] cbd3 = {3,2,2,3,3,7,7};
int[] cbd4 = {2,3,3,4,4};
int[] cbd5 = {4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7};
String this_cdb = "cdb"+Integer.toString(router_id);
int this_cbd_number = this_cdb[0];
```

I get the following error: array required, but String found
        `int this_cbd_number = this_cdb[0];`

here `router_id` can be `1` `2` `3` `4` or `5`. I know I declared `this_cdb` as `String`. But how do I reference it to the right array name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without reflection you can't do references to other variables/fields/classes from a String.
You would need to encapsulate your arrays e.g. inside another array or a `List`. Example (assuming router is indexed from `1`):

```
int[] cdb1 = {2,1,1,5,5};
int[] cbd2 = {3,1,1,2,2,6,6};
int[] cbd3 = {3,2,2,3,3,7,7};
int[] cbd4 = {2,3,3,4,4};
int[] cbd5 = {4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7};
int[][] cdb = {cdb1, cdb2, cdb3, cdb4, cdb5};
int this_cbd_number = cdb[router_id - 1][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting all of the arrays into some kind of a data structure, like a LinkedList:

```
LinkedList<int[]> arrayList = new LinkedList<>();
arrayList.add(cdb1);
arrayList.add(cdb2);
arrayList.add(cdb3);
arrayList.add(cdb4);
arrayList.add(cdb5);
int this_cbd_number = arrayList.get(router_id)[0];
```